# How to discontinue selling the products that has not been selling enough for the past 2 years in Qlik sense

Tags: qliksense

I have an Excel file with multiple tables and I have loaded it into the qlikSense.I have different product names, product IDs and their sales across four years 2011,2012,2013,2014. I have plotted a bar graph with dimension as product name, years and measure as sum(sales). I have attached the chart for reference [plotted chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbvRC.png). How can I filter the products that have not been selling enough for the past 2 years?

Comment: What's the definition for products not sold enough?

Comment: The products whose sales for the last two years is less than sales of the same product for the first two years